# How to create a form using HTML and Javascript and pass the variables to a PHP file?

Tags: javascript, php, android, jquery, html

I have created an android app, In it i want to create a form using javascript and html, In the form first I validate all the user information and then pass to a php file as a url. But the problem is I am not able to do what i just mentioned. So can someone help me with it.

here is my code

HTML form

```
<body>
<div id="id01"></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
    <form action="#" method="get" onsubmit="return ValidationEvent()">
      <label>Name :</label><br/>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" /><br/>   

      <label>Email :</label><br/>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Valid Email" /> <br/>

      <label>Gender :</label><br/>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" id="male" /><label>Male</label>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" id="female" /><label>Female</label><br/><br/>

      <label>Contact No. :</label><br/>
      <input type="text" name="contact" id="contact" placeholder="Contact No." /> <br/>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

    </form>
  </div>      

</div>
```

javascript code

```
 function ValidationEvent() {

//Storing Field Values in variables
 var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
 var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
 var contact = document.getElementById("contact").value;

 //Regular Expression For Email 
 var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

//Conditions
if (name != '' && email != '' && contact != '') {
    if(email.match(emailReg)){
        if( document.getElementById("male").checked || document.getElementById("female").checked ) {
            if (contact.length == 10) {
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }else {
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(data){
                    document.getElementById("id01").style.display = "none";
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                        document.getElementById("id01").style.display = "block";
                        document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open('GET','http://localhost/donotdel/repeat.php?name=' + name +'&email=' + email +'&contact=' + contact,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
            else{
                alert ("The Contact No. must be at least 10 digit long!");
                return false;
            }
        }
        else{
            alert ("You must select gender.....!");
            return false;
        }
    }
    else{
        alert ("Invalid Email Address...!!!");
        return false;
    }  
}
else{
    alert ("All fields are required.....!");
    return false;
 } 
 }
```

and the php file would be

```
<?php
 $name = $_GET['name']; 
 echo $name;

?>
```

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? Do you have any errors?

Comment: @svengali i am not getting any response from php at al

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute HTML and Javascript, you can use a [webview](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) but you cannot natively execute PHP on Android.

You can make a remote PHP server and define an API so your webview can call your endpoints or you can just simply code in Java to make your form.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects) object and append to it each value, then pass it through AJAX, so you can get the values from `$_POST['inputName']`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use AJAX, you can connect Javascript and PHP with AJAX.

Comment: i have used ajax..I think you didnt see my code proprly